# regexkitlite match?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, regexkitlite

i would like to get everything inbetween `&amp;v=` and `">` using a regex expression,

```
NSString *YouTubeRegex =  @"/amp;v=([^(\">)]+)/";
```

But that regex is not returning any matches ? i know the coding is correct just not the regex expression any help ?

Thanks

Comment: can we see the code in any case?

Comment: Why do you have leading and trailing slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
/amp;v=(.+?)">/
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/Lqb63CsN2p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the regex engine is Perl-like:

```
"/&amp;v=(.*)>/"
```

should do the trick.